# Помогите упростить код. JAVA

Tags: java, массивы, сравнение

Стояла следующая задача:
Пользователь вводит 20 случайных чисел.
Программа должна создать большой массив из 20 чисел и заполнить его этими числами. Затем программа создает еще 2 массива маленьких по 10 чисел. После программа должна скопировать первую половину большого массива в первый маленький массив, вторую половину - во второй, вычислить сумму чисел этих массивов, сравнить и вывести тот массив, сумма чисел которого наименьшая.

Ниже привел код, который у меня получился.

**Суть моего вопроса**: код получился слишком громоздким. И что-то мне подсказывает, что его можно существенно упростить. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] bigMass = new int[20];
    int[] smallMass1 = new int[10];
    int[] smallMass2 = new int[10];
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      bigMass[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      smallMass1[i] = bigMass[i];
    }
    for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
      smallMass2[i - 10] = bigMass[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < smallMass1.length; i++) {
      sum1 = sum1 + smallMass1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < smallMass2.length; i++) {
      sum2 = sum2 + smallMass2[i];
    }
    int min = (sum1 < sum2) ? sum1 : sum2;
    if (min == sum1)
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(smallMass1[i]);
      }
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(smallMass2[i]);
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: У вас условие ограничивает вариативность решения задачи. Можно только объединить в один цикл заполнение маленьких массивов и еще в один вычисление их суммы. Если бы не условие, то решение можно было бы сделать и простым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не java-гуру, но что бы не сделать вот так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] bigMass = new int[20];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        bigMass[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    int[] smallMass1 =  Arrays.stream(bigMass).limit(10).toArray();
    int[] smallMass2 =  Arrays.stream(bigMass).skip(10).limit(10).toArray();

    if (Arrays.stream(smallMass1).sum() < Arrays.stream(smallMass2).sum())
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smallMass1));
    else
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(smallMass2));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пока не знаком с Arrays, буду изучать:)